# How to register generic ObjectPoolProvider in DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I read [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/objectpool?view=aspnetcore-7.0) about objects pools. I have object pool policy:

```
public class DictionaryPolicy<TKey, TValue> : PooledObjectPolicy<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public override Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Create()
    {
        return new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public override bool Return(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
    {
        obj.Clear();

        return true;
    }
}
```

And now I need register it.

```
services.AddSingleton(provider =>
     provider.GetRequiredService<ObjectPoolProvider>().Create(new DictionaryPolicy()));
```

There is compile error because I have to define generic parameters for DictionaryPolicy. But I don't want to register every dictionary with specific type I use. Also, each pool of a specific dictionary type must be registered as a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible with the simple build in DI in asp.net but its perfectly valid use case if you use [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) DI. Given you are willing to use it by installing `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` nuget you would need to configure it, in simplest possible way it takes one line:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var createMethod = typeof(ObjectPoolProvider).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Create" && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    /*1*/builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
    builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(
            builder =>
            {
                /*2*/builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DictionaryPolicy<,>))
                               .As(typeof(PooledObjectPolicy<>))
                               .SingleInstance();
                builder.RegisterType<DefaultObjectPoolProvider>().As<ObjectPoolProvider>().SingleInstance();
                /*3*/builder.RegisterGeneric((c, t) =>
                {
                    var provider = c.Resolve<ObjectPoolProvider>();
                    var policy = c.Resolve(typeof(PooledObjectPolicy<>).MakeGenericType(t[0]));                        
                    return createMethod.MakeGenericMethod(t[0]).Invoke(provider, new object[] { policy })!;

                }).As(typeof(ObjectPool<>)).SingleInstance();
            }
       );
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

call to `UseServiceProviderFactory` configures Autofac as your DI;
Second line registers your custom policy implementation as base class `PooledObjectPolicy`. Finally custom factory for `ObjectPool` that basically does the same thing as in the article you posted with a bit of reflection.

To verify you can execute any controller action:

[image]

Comment: Such code will not pass the codereview  at my work ). We don't use Autofac. Thank you. This thread rather demonstrates the problem. I'm not expecting a decision right now. But I hope the MS guys see it.